# Utilizar UrlRequest do kivy

Tags: python, json

Como exatamente se utiliza o UrlRequest do kivy? No caso queria baixar uma página que retorna um arquivo json. Usando a biblioteca requests do python consigo fazer isso facilmente, porém na hora de rodar o aplicativo no celular android, ele fica minimizando sozinho, então preciso de uma alternativa. 
Esse é o código q tenho utilizando requests:

```
url = requests.get('pagina_web.json')
page = url.json()
page2 = page['chave1']['chave2']['chave3']['chave4']
```

Preciso de algo parecido utilizando UrlRequest ou outra biblioteca, mas que funcione na hora de executar o aplicativo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que essa app explica bem como funciona o UrlRequest do Kivy:

```
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button



class reqApp(App):
    def build(self):
        bt =  Button(text='Pegar Json do Bitcoin')
        bt.bind(on_press=self.make_request)
        return bt

    def make_request(self, instance):
        UrlRequest('https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/BTC/ticker/', self.print_json)

    def print_json(self, req, result):
        print result['ticker']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reqApp().run()
```

Quando se clicka no botão ele chama o `make_request` que faz uma instancia do `UrlRequest`. Quando o objeto é instanciado ele automaticamente faz uma requisição assíncrona e quando ela termina(se a requisição for bem sucedida) chama a função `print_json`.

Lembre-se é assincrono então o main loop da GUI nao vai "travar" até a request terminar, não há necessidade de usar os threads do python.

Para ter todos os detalhes dos parametros que você pode passar no UrlRequest veja https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html

PS: Utilizo a biblioteca requests no android em um app que fiz de musica e funciona normal caso queira ver: https://github.com/SamuelHaidu/OMAP

Se for muito simples pode se usar a biblioteca padrao do python o urllib2

Comment: tem como salvar o resultado desse self.print_json no UrlRequests em uma variável?

Comment: Claro, basta colocar o result em uma variável global (a forma mais simples)